# Перестал запускаться intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

перестал запускаться intellij idea 2023.2, ос Ubuntu 22.04 Выдает такое сообщение:

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.picocontainer.PicoContainer com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.getPicoContainer()'
    at com.aliyun.odps.studio.intellij.StudioMain.replaceHelpManagerIfNecessary(StudioMain.java:111)
    at com.aliyun.odps.studio.intellij.StudioMain.initComponent(StudioMain.java:96)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.MyComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(MyComponentAdapter.kt:45)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:158)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.createInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:137)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:94)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance$default(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:79)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl$createInitOldComponentsTask$1.invoke(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:404)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl$createInitOldComponentsTask$1.invoke(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:402)
    at com.intellij.ide.bootstrap.AppServicePreloadingKt$postAppRegistered$3$1.invokeSuspend(appServicePreloading.kt:142)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:789)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:734)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:759)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:322)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.7+7-b1000.6 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
/snap/intellij-idea-community/451/jbr
```

Ума не приложу, куда копать

p.s. простая переустановка не помогла

Comment: Судя по ошибкам плагин Alibaba Cloud (Aliyun) несовместим. Попробуй отключить плагин и запуститься.

Comment: @DiMithras вопрос как, gui не запускается, выдает сообщение выше и закрывается, соответственно доступа к gui настройкам у меня нет

Comment: Попробовать удалить сам файл или в блокноте настройки поправить и отключить. Проще, конечно, IntelliJ снести полностью и переустановить.

Comment: плагины лежат в папке ``C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA {версия}\plugins``. Просто удали папку с плагином оттуда

Comment: @Эникейщик там ubuntu, путь будет другим скорее всего =)

Comment: @Dmitry а, не обратил внимания. В линуксе путь ``~/.local/share/JetBrains/<product><version>`` https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо уже сам ее нашел, вот только удаление всех файлов где было Aliyun ничего не дало. Пока рабочее решение откат на предыдущую версию, тогда все работает